CORS Configuration for Cloudflare R2
i am a super rookie for this. I tried to store some of my data for analysis on cloudflare R2. And when I read it in python by pandas, it said HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. This also when I try to import the font file stored on R2 in html file. I personally can visit those files by visiting the url (not from a request sent by python script or html file). I know this has something to do with configuring the CORS. However, this is my current configuration:
[
  {
    "AllowedOrigins": [
      "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
      "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedHeaders": [
      "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [
      "*"
    ]
  }
]

But it didnt work at all. Can anyone help me?
Current config

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

the following configuration works for uploading the file via the presign url attaching the cors policy along with a sample snippet to generate presign url and command to verify the file is uploading properly or not.
[
  {
    "AllowedOrigins": [
      "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
      "PUT"
    ],
    "AllowedHeaders": [
      "Content-Type",
      "Content-Length"
    ]
  }
]

update the allowedOrigins if you planning on restricting from a specific doamins even can be added to local.
example:
[
  {
    "AllowedOrigins": [
      "http://localhost:5173",
      "https://jsonstore.online"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
      "PUT"
    ],
    "AllowedHeaders": [
      "Content-Type",
      "Content-Length"
    ]
  }
]

snippet for generating a presign url.
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const s3Client = new S3Client({
    region: "auto",
    endpoint: R2_BASE_URL,
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: R2_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: R2_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    },
});

const objectKey = "<foldername>/dog.png";

const presignedUrl = await getSignedUrl(
        s3Client,
        new PutObjectCommand({
            Bucket: R2_BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: objectKey,
        }),
        {
            expiresIn: 60 * 5, // 5 minutes
        }
    );

console.log({presignedUrl})

run the following command to upload the file via the presign url
curl -X PUT "presignUrl" -F "data=@dog.png"

Now you should be able to see the file uploaded to the r2 bucket under the folder name you have provided.
